# Can be Keycloak configured to set roles automatically based on user's properties?

Tags: authorization, keycloak

The goal is to get an access token with a custom set of roles.

My scenario is that I have an User Storage Provider SPI that looks into an Oracle DB for authentication. It also checks users permissions defined in other tables of that DB. I would set that permissions into the UserModel object returned by the SPI.

Now I would like to define in Keycloak (using the administration application) custom roles and configure them so they are included in the access token of the user depending on some rules over the user's permissions that I've set previously into the UserModel. The idea is to be flexible and allow to change the configuration between roles and the user's permissions found in DB.

I've read the theory about mappers and policies but I'm not sure how to manage it and I can't find an example that ilustrates the process.